# Re-install ubuntu

Tags: installation

I have installed in my laptop for some time now. While I was playing with partitions I accidentally (think) I destroyed the boot partition. Now I cannot open Ubuntu since GRUB is lost. Is there a way to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the files I had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try Boot-Repair:

> Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may
>   encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing
>   Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows
>   after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some
>   upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) article at the Ubuntu Documentation for more information about usage.